# How to check in C++ that identifier is declared?

Tags: c++, function, variables, reflection, declaration

I want to check at some point of code if some identifier `x` is declared, how do I do that?

I need this kind of check for different types of identifiers - variables, enum constants, functions, types, macros, etc. But for start I want to check at least variables and functions.

I need such kind of check (e.g. imaginary `declared(x)`) so that next code works e.g. for the case of int variable `x`:

```
if constexpr(declared(x)) {
    int y = x + 1;
} else {
    std::cout << "Variable 'x' not declared!" << std::endl;
}
```

For the case of macros of cause I can use `#ifdef x`, but how to do same check for variables/functions?

For the case of global non-lambda functions I figured out next code, based on overloaded functions resolution, but it needs using helper macros-based global definitions (can it be simplified more?):

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/M1rWfa)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

#define declared_func_helper(x, ...) \
    struct NotDeclared; \
    template <typename ... Args> \
    NotDeclared x(Args ...); \
    template <typename ... Args> \
    inline constexpr bool declared_func_##x(Args && ... args) { \
        return !std::is_same_v<decltype(x(args...)), NotDeclared>; \
    }

// declare some of functions
//void f(int a) {}
void g(bool b, char c) {}
    
// define helpers before or after declared functions
declared_func_helper(f);
declared_func_helper(g);

int main() {
    // check declaration of functions
    std::cout << "func 'f' declared: " << std::boolalpha << declared_func_f(int()) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "func 'g' declared: " << std::boolalpha << declared_func_g(bool(), char()) << std::endl;
}
```

which outputs:

```
func 'f' declared: false
func 'g' declared: true
```

For the case of non-global variables I implemented next code, but it also needs helpers definition through macroses:

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/dTM8Yr)

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

#define declared_var_helper(x) \
    struct NotDeclared_##x {}; \
    NotDeclared_##x x;
#define declared_var(x) \
    ([&](){ return !std::is_same_v<decltype(x), NotDeclared_##x>; }())
    
// use helpers before variables declaration
declared_var_helper(x);
declared_var_helper(y);

int main() {
    // declare some of variables
    //bool x = false;
    int y = 0;
    // ........
    // later check declaration
    constexpr bool is_declared_x = declared_var(x), is_declared_y = declared_var(y);
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << "var 'x' declared: " << is_declared_x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "var 'y' declared: " << is_declared_y << std::endl;
}
```

which outputs:

```
var 'x' declared: false
var 'y' declared: true
```

What about other cases, or easier ways to check?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want. If `x` is not declared you can't successfully compile a program that has a reference to its name.

Comment: This cannot be done in C++. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Code can be successfully compiled with absence of `x` if I do two things, first I define a global variable with same name, then wrap usage code into `if constexpr(declared(x)) { ... }` block, [see my trial](https://godbolt.org/z/eKza1P) to solve this task. Basically because global variable with type NotDeclared is defined that's why code compiles, but block is not executed because there is no such local variable. This case of local variable is solved by me this way!

Comment: The compiler checks this for you. Either way, you should use variables that are declared (no other way to do it in C++ really). This looks like a case of the [x-y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Can you add some notes on what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @utnapistim Actually my current use case is not for variables, but for a function. If client of my library didn't define some special function, then I want still to compile my code, but do some fallback code instead. Also for variable future use case is same - if my client didn't define some special global variable then I want to compile my library but do some fallback code. But variables case is for the future, but it is needed to be solved at some point.

Comment: @Arty: If I'm understanding you correctly, the canonical way of doing that is to provide a base class with a set of virtualized default implementations. The client can then inherit from that and override the functions they want to provide custom behavior. In fact this scenario is the whole reason virtual methods exist. if desired, this can also be done with function pointers in a non-OO way (albeit less elegantly).

Comment: @500-InternalServerError You suggest RunTime solution. At runtime you can do any complex stuff. But I want compile-time solution. Why?Because e.g. I have a very high-performance part of code, and in that code I want always to compile only one branch - either for defined client function or for fallback.I can't afford extra runtime bool condition check.Another issues which is more important is because sometimes such defined functions can be dozens or hundreds of different functions.And these functions may be in 3rd-party libraries,I don't want my clients to do extra work of initializing pointers

Answer (score 0):

What you can do for your function issue is to declare a global function pointer which your client has to fill in, and is set to your function by default.

For example:

```cpp
const auto Function = Function_Fallback
```

and then use `Function` everywhere.

Comment: You have a Run-Time solution. Of cause it is possible. At runtime you can do any complex stuff. But I want compile-time solution. Why?Because e.g. I have a very high-performance part of code, and in that code I want always to compile only one branch - either for defined client function or for fallback.I can't afford extra runtime bool condition check.Another issues which is more important is because sometimes such defined functions can be dozens or hundreds of different functions.And these functions may be in 3rd-party libraries,I don't want my clients to do extra work of initializing pointers

Comment: There is no runtime bool check. You are just using a function pointer, and it has the same overhead as calling a normal function.

Comment: By run-time solution I actually meant that I have to use a function through pointer. Imagine that actual function was some `inline` short function defined in client's header. If my code was using this inline function directly any compiler will inline and optimze this function call inside my code. But if function is used by pointer then first it will not be inlined and second will have no chance to be optimzed in release. I need inline optimizations for my high performant code.

Comment: Second thing which is even much more important is that there can be dozens/hundreds of such different functions and they can be defined in 3rd party libraries. With extra pointer solution all clients have to initialize pointers of all hundreds functions, i.e. doing a lot of coding work, instead of just including 3rd party library and compiling my code.

Answer (score 0):

This expands on the comment by @500-internal-server-error.

From your comment, I understand that you are trying to add customization points to your library.

The canonical way to do this in OOP is to define interface (base classes) for what you want to do, and add default implementations for them.

Then, specify (through documentation and examples) how users of your code can customize this behavior to fit their needs.

For this, you do not need to check if/what clients declare in their code.

Here is an example (using some hypotetical classes to serialize data):

```
class Document // your data class, that you needd to save
{
    int a = 0; // document data (that needs to be saved)
    int b = 1;
public:
     void save() // by default, save to xml
     {
         XmlDocument store{"document.xml"};
         save(store);
     }

     void save(OutputDocument &store)
     {
         store.add("a", to_string(a));
         store.add("b", to_string(b));
     }
};
```

customization point (OutputDocument):

```
class OutputDocument
{
public:
     virtual void add(const std::string& name, const std::string& value) = 0;
};
```

default implementation (xml):

```
class XmlDocument: public OutputDocument
{
public:
     void add(const std::string& name, const std::string& value) override; 
};
```

Customization (clients can do this):

```
class JsonDocument: public OutputDocument // store to JSON instead
{
public:
     void add(const std::string& name, const std::string& value) override; 
};
```

Clients can just say:

```
Document doc;
JsonDocument json{"document.json"};
doc.save(json); // save to json instead of the default (to xml)
```

Comment: Why can't I use interfaces? [See my comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65507539/how-to-check-in-c-that-identifier-is-declared?noredirect=1#comment115815808_65508113). One reason is that I can't afford extra virtual level in my high performant code. Second more important that hundreds of such functions may come from some 3rd-party library, and some of these functions are defined conditionally by `#ifdef ...` macros. I don't want my clients to bother forwarding all such hundreds of functions through extra virtual interfaces. I want to use 3rd party library functions directly.